# More complicated key definitions in loops/for each statements

Tags: package-writing, loops, key-value

While writing a package with a key-value interface,
I had a lot of repetitive key definitions.
Naturally, one would like to express these definitions with a loop.
When the definition contains something more complicated like `\PassOptionsToPackage`, things get messy. The degree of messiness depends on the package used for the loops. `etoolbox` complains a lot, `forarray` not so much.  Minimal working example for `forarray`:

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
    \ProvidesPackage{package}
    [2012/09/18 Example]
    \RequirePackage{keyreader}
    \RequirePackage{forarray}
    \DeclareOptionX*{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{}{Cant understand option(s): \CurrentOption}%
    }

    \CommandForEach{,}{%
    \krdDeclareOption{#1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{##1}{#1}}%
    }%
    {todonotes}

    \krdProcessOptions
```

This is the package, and the latex file is

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[todonotes=shadow]{package}
    \usepackage{todonotes}

    \begin{document}
    \todo{2 do}
    \end{document}
```

This produces the warning

```
    ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              

    l.13 {todonotes}

    ?
```

No greater harm done, pressing *return* brings it to the end. Only the *todonotes* in the documents remains of the trouble, but the todo box has a nice shadow. What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand `\CommandForEach`, you have to use a command as one token as second argument and the list element in the third argument need an additional pair of curly braces. There are better ways to parse comma separated lists.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek So, the crucial thing is this *" a command as one token as second argument"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another (or, more precisely, the same) solution with `etoolbox`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{package}
[2012/09/18 Example]
\RequirePackage{keyreader}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \krdDeclareOption{#1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{##1}{#1}}%
}

\docsvlist{todonotes}

\krdProcessOptions
```

As I tested Heikos solution I realized that earlier with `etoolbox`, I just had forgotten a closing curly bracket while redefining `\do`. Sorry for the hassle, I still hope it was useful.

Answer (score 8):

Solution using `\comma@parse` of `kvsetkeys`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{package}[2012/09/18 Example]
\RequirePackage{keyreader}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}
\DeclareOptionX*{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{}{Cant understand option(s): \CurrentOption}%
}
\def\TempDefOption#1{%
  \krdDeclareOption{#1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{##1}{#1}}%
}
\comma@parse{todonotes}\TempDefOption

\krdProcessOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is something like the following. You don't have to load *etoolbox* or any package for processing a list. The *keyreader* package has its own list processors.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\ProvidesPackage{ulysis}[2012/09/18 Example package]
\RequirePackage{keyreader}
\krdDeclareOption*{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{ulysis}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption' ignored}%
}
\newif\ifuly@verbose
\krdDeclareOption{verbose}[true]{\@nameuse{uly@verbose#1}}

% Declare options with default values that will be used when the options
% are called without user values:
\protected\def\DeclarePassedOptions#1{%
  \edef\uly@tempa{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \krdkvnormalize\uly@tempa
  % The looping macro used here is \krdfor, but the list has to be first normalized.
  \def\do##1{%
    \def\@do####1=####2=####3\@nil{%
      \krdDeclareOption{####1}[####2]{%
        \PassOptionsToPackage{########1}{####1}%
      }%
      % To avoid passing options to eventually unloaded packages:
      \AtBeginDocument{%
        \ifuly@verbose
          \krdifcsndef{ver@####1.sty}{}{%
            \@latexerr{Package '####1' wasn't loaded}
              {There are specified but unloaded packages}%
          }%
        \fi
      }%
    }%
    \@do##1==\@nil
  }%
  \expandafter\krdfor\expandafter{\uly@tempa}%
}
\DeclarePassedOptions{%
  todonotes={backgroundcolor=gray!15},xcolor=svgnames
}
\krdProcessOptions*

\endinput
```

Test document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  verbose,
  todonotes={shadow,linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=white},
  xcolor=dvipsnames
]{ulysis}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{MidnightBlue}{%
  \todo{{\bf\large 1 do}}
}

\textcolor{ForestGreen}{%
  \todo{\bf\large 2 do}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you compare it to Heikos or the one with etoolbox, it seems a bit complicated for someone with an only rudimentary understanding of TeX. But if you would provide a high level interface for *loops/for eachs* that hides your code in keyreader, i'd be happy to use it.

Comment: P.S. The most efficient way to communicate with the author of todonotes would, IMO, be the use of his email address. He provided it in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf). Just saying ;-)

Comment: OK, I have removed the recommendations for *todonotes* package.

Comment: The most important thing to me is that you can sort this out with Hendrik. An email just seems directer than a note left on a random website. Further, my documentation of keyreader does not mention `\krdlistloop`. I have other questions concerning keyreader, the most pressing concerns choicekeys. I think I first should update the TeX installation before dropping it here. Do you recommend reading keyreaders source as second step?

Comment: I am sorry, I am poor with - acutally, I lack time for - documentation. WRT choice keys, you can send an email to me.